# drawbox don't work on remote server and works on local

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a completely weird problem.

I need to draw the text over the filled rectangle. The problem is that the command line command that work on my local machine don't work on the server! To be precise, only `drawbox` command don't work.

Here's the command.

`ffmpeg -i shake.mp4 -vf "scale=300:150,setsar=1/1,drawbox=w=300: h=16: x=0: y=134: color=0x1a5757: t=1000000,drawtext=x=5: y=136: fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='fdsf': fontcolor=0xd44e4e"  -c:v h264 -preset medium -b:v 256k  -f mp4 shake_conv.mp4`

### Clarification

It seems, that my question is unclear. Ok, here's clarification.

> I need to draw the text over the filled rectangle.

It means, that, at first, I have a video. Then I would like to draw a bar at the [0; 134] with width 300px and height 16px, painted with #1A5757 color. And over that bar should be placed a text.

> The problem is that the command line command that work on my local machine don't work on the server!

It means that I have 2 environments: local machine (my Mac OS X 10.9.2 with ffmpeg 2.0.2 installed) and the server (Debian 7 with ffmpeg 1.0.8 installed. Quite old, dunno, but no errors were in this case; can't find any info about version dependency).

The last part,

> the command line command that work on my local machine don't work on the server
>
> To be precise, only `drawbox` command don't work.

means that the same command above draws the bar I need in my local environment but don't draw it on the server side. The text is drawed correctly in both cases. One more time: the text is drawed, the bar isn't drawed. That's my problem. I need a bar over the video. And there aren't any bars when I execute this command on server.

Now, I hope, this is quite clear.

Here's the output.

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 12 2013 11:57:09 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --dis  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'shake.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf52.40.0
  Duration: 00:00:29.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2243 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 2111 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'llll.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] profile High, level 1.3
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] 264 - core 132 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options:  cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=256 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'llll.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 300x150 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], q=-1--1, 256 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libfaac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] channel element 1.15 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] TYPE_FIL: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
Multiple frames in a packet from stream 1
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] SSR not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x228d5c0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/MPlayer/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
frame=  731 fps=244 q=32766.0 Lsize=    1497kB time=00:00:29.16 bitrate= 420.6kbits/s    
video:1028kB audio:447kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.533339%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] frame I:5     Avg QP:27.90  size:  6997
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] frame P:578   Avg QP:28.74  size:  1732
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] frame B:148   Avg QP:25.26  size:   107
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] consecutive B-frames: 59.5% 40.5%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] mb I  I16..4: 25.6%  9.1% 65.4%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] mb P  I16..4:  2.1%  1.1%  3.8%  P16..4: 12.3% 15.3% 15.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:49.7%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 17.6%  3.3%  0.9%  direct: 0.5%  skip:76.9%  L0:39.7% L1:57.5% BI: 2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] final ratefactor: 26.03
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] 8x8 transform intra:14.3% inter:23.4%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 54.1% 68.9% 58.9% inter: 17.7% 19.5% 10.0%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 58% 33%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 12% 22%  6%  6%  8%  7%  9% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 19% 20%  5%  5%  7%  8%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 25% 19%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.6% UV:1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] ref P L0: 70.2% 11.0% 10.1%  8.5%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] ref B L0: 94.3%  5.7%
[libx264 @ 0x229e7a0] kb/s:287.75
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Including the complete `ffmpeg` console output is infinitely more informative than just stating that it "don't work".

Comment: does the server have that fontfile?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard As I said, `drawbox command don't work`. It means that no box is drawed.

Comment: @rogerdpack The text is drawed correctly. The box isn't drawed at all.

Comment: 1.0.8 is a bit old...

Comment: Does a recent build of `ffmpeg` work as expected? See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page for links.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Well, we installed the last version on our server and it works fine (1.0.8 seems to draw only draw a frame around video). My problem is solved now, but 2.2 is in test Debian repos now, so it can cause some system problems in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had installed the latest version (2.2 back in the days) on our server and it works fine (1.0.8 seems to draw only draw a frame around video).